# When i put my usb flash drive in nothing happens, but there is sound for usb

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

my title said everything, when i put my usb flash drive in nothing happens, but there is sound for usb. In my computer nothing shows.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including equipment information (i.e. brand and model numbers) of the computer, what OS is being used, what is on the USB (is it formatted) and what you expect to see. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Please specify the model of your PC, whether it has USB3.0 port, and whether your flash drive is USB3 or USB2 drive.

Comment: I also assume that you did try to completely reboot your system before identifying the problem..

Comment: Hopefully, your title doesn't say everything because in that case, there isn't enough information to solve the problem.  In addition to what's already been asked, are you saying that you get the USB recognition sound for other USB devices, but get no sound for your flash drive, and the system doesn't show it?  Can you try the drive on another computer?  Where are you looking for the drive (pop-up auto-run dialog, device manager, file manager)?  Did the drive ever work?  Have you done anything to it, like partitioning or formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Sound means that your device has sensed VBUS from your port, and asserted "connect" event" - pulled D+ high. This results in connect sound. However, it looks like your device failed to respond to enumeration sequence that must follow the connect event. The investigation depends on whether the port is USB3.0 port, and if the device is USB3 device.

If the drive is USB2, failure to enumerate can be caused:

(a) failure in digital logic in flash drive: drive fails to respond to USB_RESET signaling, or fails to respond to GET_DESCRIPTOR inquiry. Did you try your flash drive in any other computer?

(b) Out-of range termination in the flash drive, such that the host detects false disconnect event;

(c) Host port has too much sensitivity in disconnect detector, so with (b) it causes premature disconnect and failure of enumeration.

(d) Host failed to provide correct chirp sequence, or chirp amplitude is marginal..

To find the root cause,

1. check if the flash drive works in any other (preferably older) computer;
2. check if any other flash drive works in the failing port;
3. check if your USB port recognizes any other USB device, keyboard, mice, webcam, something.
4. Use a [tool to visualize USB bus activity](http://www.kage-electronics.com/PRODUCTS.php), to see if the enumeration attempt happens only three-four times, or D+ cycles forever. In case of USB3 drive the dongle will show if the flash drive first tried to connect at Super-Speed rate.
5. Use [USB protocol analyzer](http://teledynelecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/protocoloverview.aspx?seriesid=280&capid=103&mid=511) to determine the cause of failure.

Answer (score 2):

Only mounted filesystems show in My Computer. Drives show in Disk Management. If the device shows up in Disk Management, nothing is wrong.

Sometimes filesystems are mounted automatically on insertion. This has created the unfortunate expectation that this will always happen. Not having a filesystem mount automatically is not unusual and does not indicate a problem if the device appears in the Device Manager and in Disk Management. You can mount any filesystems from Disk Management.